# Should a factory return list of elements?

Tags: c#, oop, domain-driven-design, factory

I am trying to use DDD, and i have a requirement to create some kind of entities. The interface for this method is something similiar to this:

```
public IEnumerable<Entity> CreateEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities, decimal someOtherParameter);
```

One thing of note is that inside this method there is a group by on the `entities`.

A simplified (by much) example of what i have now:

```
public IEnumerable<Entity> CreateEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities, decimal someOtherParameter)
{
    var grouped = entities.GroupBy(x=>x.SomeProperty);
    var result = new List<Entity>();
    foreach(var item in grouped)
    {
        result.Add(CreateEntity(item, someOtherParameter));
    }
    return result;
}

public Entity CreateSingleEntity(IEnumerable<Entity> entities, decimal something)
{
    return new Entity(){
        something = something,
        something2 = entities.Sum(x=>x.Amount),
        something3 = entities.First().something3
    };
}
```

Previously i had this methods as a static on the `Entity` class. (The one returning single Entity was private) Im thinking about moving this logic to a factory. What's the best way to accomplish this? My ideas:

- Have the factory with CreateSingleEntity method, and the other one
  would be in the domain service.
- Move both methods to factory, and keep the CreateSingleEntity as private (I always need to do the group by part, when im creating new Entities)

Answer (score 1):

A factory doesn't necessarily have to be a new class. Often another aggregate is responsible for creating new entities or aggregates. What does your language say? For example `var post = forum.NewPost(user)`.

Comment: I don't have the aggreagate root that could be the "forum" you mentioned. I have only the use case. Using your forum example, the process could be described as follows: the user selects some posts, and then, using the selected posts, system creates a new, single post for each of the authors of the original post, that contains all of the content of given posts.

Comment: So you're cloning/copying posts? Is that the language used by your business? `yourAggregate.Copy()?`

Comment: Rather aggregating a list of aggregates into a new one. Look at my example- there is stuff like list.Sum(x>x.Amount) and so on.

Comment: Then it might indeed fit better in a separate class. I would keep the two methods together though.